# How to check that the row inserted is newly inserted in gridview control using javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

How can I check whether a row inserted is new in gridview.  I am able to get the id but I need to check whether it is the newly inserted one. Is there any way using javascript?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One Solution that we can think off is that as a part of validation we will be calling  some java script .Use some flag to set, so that insertion of new row can be identified.